# Pricing rule : Percent of product price discount

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

I want to set up a "buy more save more" rule in Magento where one gets a 20% discount for every 150USD spent in a specific set of product categories.

Is it possible to make sure products from excluded categories are not taken into account in the "spend 150USD" condition rule ?

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks
Quentin